# How to display the Lat modified user Name using Flows

Tags: visual-workflow

Hi Can anyone help me in how to display the Last Modified user Name in Hierarchy look up filled on User Object. when the user tries to deactivates the another user by changing the IsActive = false need to display username in "Hierarchy look up" custom filed.The user which who makes IsActivate = flase. Currently i am using flow , used below formula
**$Record__Prior > Last Modified By ID > Full Name**  but its not working.
Thank you in Advance.
Regards,
Vinay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We may need to use `{!$Record__Prior.LastModifiedBy.Name}` instead of `{!$Record__Prior.LastModifiedById.Name}`

Comment: Thank you Kamal